# Solr edismax not using Logical Operators AND/OR

Tags: solr, edismax

Just got an issue where our solr 6.6 doesn't seem to be using logical operators (AND,OR,NOT) as operators but is actually search for the words. So results that should only have a few hundred hits now have thousands. We are using the edismax parser.

Solr Query: Apple AND Google

```
"debug":{
"rawquerystring":"Apple AND Google",
"querystring":"Apple AND Google",
"parsedquery":"(+(DisjunctionMaxQuery((cm_city_t:apple | cm_credit_t:apple | cm_notes_t:apple | cm_state_t:apple | cm_country_t:apple | cm_description_t:apple | cm_caption_writer_s:Apple | cm_photographer_t:apple)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((cm_city_t:and | cm_credit_t:and | cm_notes_t:and | cm_state_t:and | cm_country_t:and | cm_description_t:and | cm_caption_writer_s:AND | cm_photographer_t:and)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((cm_city_t:google | cm_credit_t:google | cm_notes_t:google | cm_state_t:google | cm_country_t:google | cm_description_t:google | cm_caption_writer_s:Google | cm_photographer_t:google))))/no_coord",
"parsedquery_toString":"+((cm_city_t:apple | cm_credit_t:apple | cm_notes_t:apple | cm_state_t:apple | cm_country_t:apple | cm_description_t:apple | cm_caption_writer_s:Apple | cm_photographer_t:apple) (cm_city_t:and | cm_credit_t:and | cm_notes_t:and | cm_state_t:and | cm_country_t:and | cm_description_t:and | cm_caption_writer_s:AND | cm_photographer_t:and) (cm_city_t:google | cm_credit_t:google | cm_notes_t:google | cm_state_t:google | cm_country_t:google | cm_description_t:google | cm_caption_writer_s:Google | cm_photographer_t:google))",

"QParser":"ExtendedDismaxQParser",
"altquerystring":null,
"boost_queries":null,
"parsed_boost_queries":[],
"boostfuncs":null,
"filter_queries":["an_sas_s:\"Photo System \\- P1\" AND an_security_group_s:\"P1.Leaders\""],
"parsed_filter_queries":["+an_sas_s:Photo System - P1 +an_security_group_s:P1.Leaders"],
```

You can see the "and" is being included as a search term in our fields. I'm not sure why its doing this. I have found that if I drop down to the dismax parser it works fine. I'm new to developing and working with solr, but my understanding is edismax is the better parser to use and should be way more advanced. Could this be a configuration issue with the response handler or something else?

Comment: I ended up solving this issue. Since I'm new to Solr and took over this application from another vendor I'm still learning. What was causing this issue is one of the default fields in the request handler was not correct, cm_keywords_txt should have been cm_keywords_ts. Once I corrected that field the edismax is correctly using AND/OR as operators now.